# Publish Facebook Post Feed on Facebook Page with Old Date (Year Only)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using the code below to publish posts on Facebook Page using Facebook SDK :
http://facebooksdk.net/ like below

```
        string accessToken = "[AccessTokenValue]"; 
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        Dictionary<string, object> PostArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        PostArgs["link"] = "www.yahoo.com";
        PostArgs["message"] = "Test";
        PostArgs["name"] = "Test";
        PostArgs["caption"] = "Test";
        PostArgs["description"] = "Test";
        Facebook.JsonObject results = fb.Post("/[PageID]/feed", PostArgs) as Facebook.JsonObject;
```

And the above code working Good ..but i want to handle another thing on my posts .. I want to create my posts with old dates not with current datetime  ... I want to be able to change the created_date ..There is something on facebook when you create a post you can change its creation time by : 
Choose the top-right arrow in your post -> Change Date -> Select a year only .. that will allow you to publish post with undefined month or day ...so any suggestion for how can i handle that using Graph API ??????

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the year first, then do like that:

[image]

This API Documentation is located at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios/#backdating

Example code of php to calculate the past year (return unix timestamp) for backdated_time parameter was:

```
<?php
echo strtotime('-1 years');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks 林果皞,
Can I handle my posts without specifying Month and Day ..Only to specificity They Year only ??

Comment: It's all about unix timestamp (in seconds since year 1970). So what you can do is minus years from current time in your code, to put inside backdated_time parameter. I've already show you the php example strtotime('-1 years');. In other words, the formula is 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP － TOTAL_SECONDS_IN_1_YEAR = backdated_time